# La séparation précoce d'avec / avec la mère biologique

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Boris Cyrulnik s'est positionné à plusieurs reprises contre la
> gestation pour autrui, notamment au titre des effets délétères sur la
> vie entière qu'aurait la séparation précoce **d'avec** la mère
> biologique...

([lien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Cyrulnik))

Quelle est la différence entre "d'avec" et "avec" ?

Comment: On ***se** sépare **de** quelqu'un*, donc *d'avec* est intuitif, le petit Robert ne donne que des exemples *séparation de* que ce soit pour des personnes  ou des objets ; on ***sépare** deux personnes, qui sont l'une **avec** l'autre*, l'acteur de la séparation est extérieur dans ce cas : « jugement de séparation avec enfants ».

Comment: … on peut envisager : *séparation* **d'avec**, c'est l'action ; *séparation* **avec**, le résultat.

Comment: @Personne Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 2):

La définition du TLFi qui s'applique au mot « séparation » dans ce contexte est la suivante.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9paration))
> **Fait, action de séparer, de se séparer; résultat de l'action.**
> **II.** − [L'action concerne une ou les diverses part. d'un tout, un ou les divers élém. d'un ensemble]
> **A.** − [Corresp. à *séparer* 1<sup>re</sup>et 2<sup>e</sup> Section II A]
> **2.** [L'action concerne des pers.]
> **Séparation (de qqn) avec/d'avec qqn**.

On voit donc qu'il n'y a pas de différence, que l'on choisisse « avec » ou « d'avec ».

Comment: Oui (mais ce n'est peut-être que moi), comme *avec* porte la connotation d'être ensemble qui est à l'opposé du sens dans cette phrase, *d'avec* a l'avantage de porter la connotation d'éloignement dans le **d'**.

Comment: @XouDo Je suis entièrement d'accord, « d'avec » me semble préférable pour cette raison même que vous avancez, et de plus la connotation  additionnelle de moyen que l'on trouve dans  « avec » est éliminée (« On opère la séparation avec le succinate ammonique exactement d'après le § 124,1 , c . Il n'y a pas moyen de séparer ces deux métaux l'un d'avec l'autre ... »). https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Trait%C3%A9_d_analyse_chimique_quantitative/uOUMAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22la+s%C3%A9paration+avec%22&pg=PA295&printsec=frontcover  (1/2)

Comment: @XouDo Lorsque je dis « pas de différence », je veux dire « pas de différence selon le sens que l'on peut donner à chaque option en vertu des définitions dans les dictionnaires ». (2/2)

Comment: @XouDo J'ai la même impression.